# Axios get request is working but post request is not working in react native, node js. In thunder client(VS code extension) all working fine

Tags: node.js, react-native, axios

In react native axios post request is not working its throwing 404 response but get request is working well, I'm using node js. In below following code the get request route "http://10.0.2.2:8080/auth/" is working, In same route"http://10.0.2.2:8080/auth/login" post is not working from axios react-native.

Node js

```
/server.js

const http = require('http');
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('./app');
const { mongoConnect } = require('./service/mongoConnect');

const PORT  = 8080;

const server = http.createServer(express);

async function loadStartup(){
    await mongoConnect();
   
    server.listen(PORT, () => { 
        console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
     });
}

loadStartup();
```

```
/app.js

const cors = require('cors');
const morgan  = require('morgan');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const authRouter = require('./routes/auth/auth.router');

const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan("combined"));
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/auth',authRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

```
/auth.router.js


const express= require('express');

const {register, 
      login,
      verifyOTP,
      forgotPassword,
      resetPassowrd
    } = require("../../controllers/auth.controller.js");
const { verifyResetToken } = require('../../middleware/verifyResetToken.js')

const authRouter = express.Router();

authRouter.get('/',(req,res) =>res.send({test: "this is an test route"}))
authRouter.post('/register',register);
authRouter.post('/login',login);
authRouter.post('/verifyOTP', verifyOTP);
authRouter.post('/forgotPassword', forgotPassword);
authRouter.post("/resetPassword",verifyResetToken,resetPassowrd);

module.exports = authRouter;
```

```
/auth.controller.js

async function login(req, res) {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const loginUser = await findUserByEmail(email);
    console.log("login",email,password)
    if(!loginUser) {
        return res.status(404).send({ error: "Login User is not found" });
    }
    if(!loginUser.authentication.verified) {
        const existAccount = await findUserByEmail(email);
        const OTP = await generateNewOTP(existAccount._id);

        sendOTPByEmail(email, OTP);
        return res.status(404).send({
            id: existAccount._id,
            verified: loginUser.authentication.verified,
            error: "Verify your account!"
        });
    }
    const passwordCheck = await bcrypt.compareSync(password, loginUser.authentication.password);

    if(!passwordCheck) return res.status(400).send({ error: "Invaild Credentials" });
    const token = jwt.sign({
        userId: loginUser._id,
        userName: loginUser.name,
    }, "secret");

    const vaildLoginRes = {
        message: "Login Sucessfu1...!",
        id: loginUser._id,
        userGender: loginUser.gender,
        completedProfile: loginUser.authentication.completedProfile,
        token
    }

    loginUser.authentication.isUserLoggedIn = true;
    loginUser.authentication.loginToken = token;
    loginUser.save();
    return res.status(200).send(vaildLoginRes);
}
```

React native

```
const login = async (email:string, password:string) =>{
        try {
            const loginInfo = { email, password }
            console.log(loginInfo);
             const result = await axios.post('http://10.0.2.2:8080/auth/login',loginInfo);
             
             console.log(result.data);
            setAuthState({ 
                token: result.data.token,
                authenticated: true
            });

            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${result.data.token}`;

            await SecureStore.setItemAsync(AUTH_KEY,result.data.token);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return
        }
    }
```

I tried Axois instence with base_url that also not working, Kindly help me...

[Thunder client API call reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhoDB.png)

Comment: first of all, how you do your post request ? and what endpoint do you hit ?

Comment: "Not working" is pretty vague, can you add what happens/ any error messages to your question please

Comment: @Abe Error:  [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404] in VS code terminal (console.log())

Comment: @cantdocpp   I added reference image above "Thunder client API call reference image", Please check it

Comment: you're making post request to ```10.0.2.2``` while your thunder client is making post request to ```localhost```. And your thunder client API image shows successful post request there

Comment: have you export your login controller function ?

Comment: @cantdocpp Yes you're right, In react native for android emulators if use localhost axios will throw network error so that's why I'm using 10.0.2.2 IP address for API calls in react native. (localhost =  10.0.2.2 in react native)

Comment: @cantdocpp Yes I exported My  login controller function